# How do I convert my date into a slightly different format

Tags: python, formatdatetime

date = '9/4/2020'.

Now on excel I converted using the format TEXT(date,'YYYYMMDD'), how do I replicate the same in python?

I tried using the datetime function

`d = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d')`

but I get the value error 
`ValueError: time data '9/4/2020' does not match format '%Y%m%d'`

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python this is called `strptime` (string parse time, ie get time object from a string) and `strftime` (string from time, get a string representation from a time object - the reverse process).

The various time symbols are listed in the Python dcoumentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). You need to describe the way the time is formatted exactly, including the separators (such as `/` or `-`). In between, you denote year, month,day, etc. according to the code in the docs. So in your case:

```
d = datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%M/%Y')
```

Would get you the time object, and then you could use

```
print(datetime.strftime(d, '%Y%M%d'))
```

to get the new one.

Or in one line:

```
d = strftime(strptime('9/4/2020', '%d/%M/%Y'), '%Y%M%d')
```

should work. (Assuming day comes first.)

Comment: thanks, but how do I convert to TEXT(date,'YYYYMMDD') format in python. I am still getting datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 4, 0, 7) as the output.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to include that

Comment: thanks for the explanation Josh - for some reason when I add d = datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%M/%Y') followed by print(datetime.strftime('%Y%M%d', d)) I get an error TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object.

Comment: yes I think its working now! appreciate your help again and the explanation !

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want output like this:

```
date = '9/4/2020'
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%M/%Y')
print(d)
```

Output:

```
2020-01-09 00:04:00
```

Comment: %M will return the minute. you need %m for getting the month

Answer (score 0):

first you need to use lower case m in the format. after converting to datetime, just convert back to string using [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

```
d = datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

another option is just split the string date:

```
f"{date.split('/')[2]}{date.split('/')[1].zfill(2)}{date.split('/')[0].zfill(2)}"

'20200409'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
d = datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%M/%Y')  # Convert string to date
new_date_format = d.strftime("%Y%m%d")  # Set your custom date format
print('My new Date format: {}'.format(new_date_format)). # Print the result
```

Comment: what is the new date you get for input date = '9/4/2020'?

Comment: I think I jumped the gun here - I am getting this as output 'My new Date format: 20200104', which is not what I was after.

Comment: @PrasKam yes. you need to use lowercase m in strftime and strptime. uppercase will return minutes and not month.